# Getting An Image from The ArDrone 2.0, And Using cv2

Tags: python, string, opencv, ar.drone

I am trying to obtain images from the ArDrone 2.0 and using Python OpenCV, cv2, to process images and create a controller.

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pydrone import libardrone

drone = libardrone.ARDrone()
cap = drone.image

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I keep getting this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ArDrn/7/drony.py", line 14, in <module>
    ret, frame = cap
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you might need to change the logic slightly to check if cap is None before trying to use it:

```
while(True):
    cap = drone.image
    if not cap:
        time.sleep(0.1)   # or something to save just a touch of CPU spin time, optional
        continue
    ret, frame = cap
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

It may be that while it is in the middle of switching images or some time like that, there may be a period of time when cap is None.  Additionally, it seems you were not updating cap to point to a new image each loop, so it's possible that could be an issue too.

Comment: Yup This seem to solve the problem. However, I just realized that drone.image is a string not an image. I just need to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong.

The pydrone library doesn't work with AR.Drone 2.0 video streams (and I know none that does).

There are two major changes in AR.Drone 2.0:

- The stream is on TCP;
- It is H264 based, with Parrot custom headers.

You can see the video from the drone using `ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555` (possibly with an horrendous latency).

There is more information on the AR.Drone 2.0 video in the [development foruns](https://projects.ardrone.org/boards/1/topics/show/4282).

Answer (score 1):

As mangon mentioned, video support is broken in libardrone.
But you don't need libardrone to access the video feed. Here is a simple example with OpenCV:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')
running = True
while running:
    # get current frame of video
    running, frame = cam.read()
    if running:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: 
            # escape key pressed
            running = False
    else:
        # error reading frame
        print 'error reading video feed'
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```